# WSO2 ESB - how to test Mediator with SoapUI

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm new to WSO2 and ESB topic in general. I'm trying to make a simple example with content based routing mediator. In particular this is the sequence XML:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CBRSimple">
    <in>
        <log category="INFO" level="full" separator=",">
            <property name="message" value="SOAP Message received on ESB"/>
        </log>
        <filter regex=".*/VISA.*" source="get-property('To')">
            <then>
                <send>
                    <endpoint key="VISAEndpoint"/>
                </send>
            </then>
            <else>
                <send>
                    <endpoint key="AMEXEndpoint"/>
                </send>
            </else>
        </filter>
    </in>
</sequence>
```

I would like to check if the destination of the request contains the word VISA and redirect the message to VISAEndpoint (a Web service deployed on WSO2 AS at **localhost:9763/services/VisaProcessingService**)

ESB is deployed and listening on the following ports:
HTTP: 8281
HTTPS: 8244

Then I created a SOAP UI Test with a sample SOAP MEssage based on VISAEndpoint Wsdl and I sent the SOAP request to the following url: 
**localhost:8281/services/VISAProcessingService**
ESB logs shows that a soap message is received because soap header is printed out, but then the request is not redirected. If I check esb logs, i don't find any errors, but it seems that soap message doesn't pass through the esb sequence.
My question is :
1)Is this the correct way to test with soap UI the esb sequence?
2)If yes, could someone help me to figure out the reason of the test not working? 
  If no, could you suggest the right approach to test this sample?

Thank you very much in advance,
Regards

Giovanni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your regular expression, you should replace `.*/VISA.*` with `.*/Visa.*`

Property 'To' contains : **/services/VisaProcessingService**